# PHP test if POST is empty from FORM fields

Tags: php

I've a FORM that is filled out by a user/visitor on the webpage. I've added JavaScript to secure as much as possible, but really want to check even on the PHP side that there is DATA in the $_POSTs.

Is the below CODE correct? I want to accomplish that NONE of the POSTed fields are EMPTY, meaning that the fields in the FORM was submitted as BLANK.

```
if (empty($_POST["firstname"]) || empty($_POST["lastname"]) || empty($_POST["cellphone"]) || empty($_POST["email"]) {
    header("Location: http://www.domain.com/error.php?ec=empty");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: You could indeed just test it, no? Just a remark - the fields will not be marked as empty if they have a space in it. If you want to remove all the spaces, you should use [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).

Comment: @arbitter Thank you for the TRIM recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($_POST["firstname"]==""||$_POST["lastname"]==""||$_POST["cellphone"]==""||$_POST["email"]=="")
{
    header("Location: http://www.domain.com/error.php?ec=empty");
    exit();
}
```

Try this instead

Answer (score 2):

Empty isn't a particularly good validation tool when used blindly and on it's own.

From the PHP manual page it will return true if:

> ```
> "" (an empty string)
> 0 (0 as an integer)
> 0.0 (0 as a float)
> "0" (0 as a string)
> NULL
> FALSE
> array() (an empty array)
> $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
> ```

Regarding the variables that you've used the likely values would pass as expected **but** I could just put some whitespace ("     ") in the form fields and have it pass. You will want to `trim($_POST["lastname"])` and others before you check it against `empty()`.

One other thing to think about in the future is that `empty()` returns TRUE for 0 or 0.0 which is often undesirable behaviour. For example if your form asked me the age of my children and one of them was only recently born, I would put in `0` and `empty()` wouldn't accept it.

For your specified case, `empty()` and `trim()` should suffice but you should be aware of it's behaviour for any future validations!

Comment: Thank you very much for this input! Would I just use the trim() directly in my IF statement or do I need to put the $_POSTs in a STRING/VARIABLE like $lastname = trim($_POST["lastname"]) in order to accomplish my desired result?

Comment: Depends on your version of PHP. PHP < 5.5 you'll need to do `$lastname = trim($_POST['lastname']; if (empty($lastname)) ...` but 5.5 you can do `if (empty(trim($_POST['lastname'])))...`